# Pandas selecting columns - best habit and performance

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

There are many different ways to select a column in a `pandas.DataFrame` (same for rows). I am wondering if it makes any difference and if there are any performance and style recommendations.

E.g., if I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((10,4)), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df.head()
```

[image]

There are many different ways to select e.g., column `d`

- 1) `df['d']`
- 2) `df.loc[:,'d']` (where `df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]`)
- 3) `df.loc[:]['d']`
- 4) `df.ix[:]['d']`
- 5) `df.ix[:,'d']`

Intuitively, I would prefer 2), maybe because I am used to the `[row_indexer,column_indexer]` style from `numpy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `ipython`'s magic function `%timeit` to find out the best performant method.
The results are:

```
%timeit df['d']
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.35 µs per loop

%timeit df.loc[:,'d']
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.3 µs per loop

%timeit df.loc[:]['d']
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

%timeit df.ix[:]['d']
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.4 µs per loop

%timeit df.ix[:,'d']
10000 loops, best of 3: 53 µs per loop
```

It turns out that the 1st method is considerably faster than others.

Comment: Thanks! I find it quite surprising that there is such a large discrepancy between `[:,'e']` and `[:]['e']`

Comment: `df.loc[:] is df`. So `df.loc[:]['d']` is essentially `df['d']` with an extra little overhead of `df.loc[:]`.

Comment: I want to stress that the 'chained indexing' like `df.loc[:]['d']` is really not recommended! See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy. For accesing the row it is no problem, but when you also assign to it, it can be a problem in certain cases.